# mousePressed method won't respond

Tags: java, mouselistener

I'm trying to do something very basic: write program that will draw a line on a frame between two points: the point that the mouse was pressed on and the point where the mouse was released on.

I have these classes:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Line implements Drawable{
    private int x1,x2,y1,y2;
    public Line( int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2){
        this.x1=x1;
        this.x2=x2;
        this.y1=y1;
        this.y2=y2;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public interface Drawable {
    public void draw(Graphics g);
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LinePanel extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

    public LinePanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Point p1, p2;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                p1 = e.getPoint();
                System.out.println("pressed");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("clicked");

            }
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                p2 = e.getPoint();
                lines.add(new Line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y));
            }

        });
        System.out.println("after add mouselistener");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Line l : lines) {
            l.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LaunchLinesGui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        LinePanel panel=new LinePanel();
        frame.add(panel);
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I press themouse on any place on the frame I get no response and even the `System.out.println`'s of `mousePressed` methods are not printed on the console.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may have to add the MouseListener to the JFrame rather than the JPanel.

Comment: What if he has several panels in the frame then? He only wants to have mouse action listeners for that particular panel, not the whole frame.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't you be creating a MouseListener() instead of an Adapter?

Comment: Are your points even populating with data properly?

Comment: MouseAdapter implements MouseListener so it's more general

Comment: I've had issues like this before and usually its related to which component has focus. I'm guessing the frame has focus and all the events are being delivered to it and not the panel.

Comment: So you have to call setFocused(true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size/location of the components added to a frame.

The reason your panel has a size of (0, 0) is because you add the panel to the frame AFTER you make the frame visible so the layout manager is never invoked.

Also, you should not set the size of the frame you should let the layout manager do its job by invoking the pack() method on the frame.

The proper order of your code should be:

```
    LinePanel panel=new LinePanel();

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    //frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Also when you do custom painting the panel is responsible for determining its own size, so you also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}
```

Now the layout manager can do its job properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't set the size of the panel and the clicks inside the **frame** were not caught inside the **panel** .

The fix was to add `setSize(500, 500);` in `LinePanel` constructor.

Comment: This may fix the problem but it is not the proper solution. You only have the problem because of improper program design. You should not set the size of the panel, that is the job of the layout manager.